# Datepicker UI mostrar div si es domingo o sabado

Tags: javascript, datepicker

como dice el titulo, necesito que en mi datepicker UI, muestre un div si es sabado o domingo, tengo el siguiente codigo, pero no me funciona.

```
onSelect: function(date) {
    var day = new Date(date).getDay();
    console.log("Selected weekday " + day);

    if (day == 6) {
        console.log("domingo");
         $('#delivery_time_normal').hide();
    } else {
        console.log("no es domingo");
         $('#delivery_time_saturday').show();
    }
}
```

¿ En que puedo estar fallando ?

Dejo un fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pentakill/hg90qr6t/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es simple, en JavaScript, con Date *0* es considerado *Domingo*

Tienes que cambiar *6* por *0*

Con 6 estás comprobando si es sábado

```js
function onSelect(date) {
    var day = new Date(date).getDay();
    console.log("Selected weekday " + day);

    if (day === 0) {
        console.log("domingo");
    } else {
        console.log("no es domingo");
    }
}

onSelect(new Date())
```

A continuación una tabla de referencia:

| Número | Nombre del día |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Domingo |
| 1 | Lunes |
| 2 | Martes |
| 3 | Miércoles |
| 4 | Jueves |
| 5 | Viernes |
| 6 | Sábado |

---

**Edición**

Ya que recibimos el formato de `dd/mm/yy`, haremos un `split` y ordenaremos la fecha para un formato admisible

https://jsfiddle.net/cwhs0j8q/

Comment: Todo bien, pero funciona solo si es en ingles, el problema es cuando esta en español: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pentakill/hg90qr6t/1/

Te dejo un fiddle para que lo veas.

Comment: @EduardoLeon Recibimos la fecha en un formato `dd/mm/yy` lo cual no es admisible para fechas, podemos hacer un `split` y ordenarlo al formato admisible, he hecho una edición

Comment: Puedes invertir el parámetro recibido de forma fácil:`let dateYmd = date.split('/').reverse().join('-');`